# Jasper Report image Error

Tags: image, jasper-reports

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="null" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0a01e24e-d4df-490e-8b8c-c9c06a7e21b1">
    <parameter name="HEADER_SERIAL" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Integer.valueOf($P{HEADER_SUB_SERIAL})]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="HEADER_SUB_SERIAL" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM company_details) cd]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="company_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="address_1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="postal_code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="website" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="banner" class="java.lang.Object"/>
    <field name="town" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="province" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="country" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="telephone_1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="logo" class="java.lang.Object"/>
    <field name="email" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="366" y="48" width="59" height="16" uuid="5114943c-a544-4c53-9173-fa4d4ef13eab"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[P.O BOX]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="366" y="17" width="59" height="16" uuid="6e8af721-752a-4d09-8bf1-60c06a8a282d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Website    ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="366" y="32" width="59" height="16" uuid="81c74b97-4910-4dce-bd2b-a5f83e827e84"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Email]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="366" y="2" width="189" height="15" uuid="3ef09040-0f8e-4542-ac48-3b08efa6f383"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{company_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="441" y="17" width="114" height="15" uuid="1a8d5ba4-2837-450c-9552-01e7e6ded58c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{website}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="441" y="33" width="114" height="15" uuid="bea94c57-63de-469c-8993-3cb25bd66dfb"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="366" y="63" width="59" height="16" uuid="b8797b80-b8a6-4d5c-8225-91f89960fe80"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Country]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="441" y="48" width="62" height="15" uuid="f2d6ddbb-0c94-4ce8-b96e-213762d8a591"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="441" y="63" width="114" height="15" uuid="0926bdda-3fcb-4d15-b5fb-bd812e39279b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{country}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="503" y="48" width="52" height="15" uuid="8f8acd7b-1fea-4fcb-a17e-db1d70bb4e30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{postal_code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image scaleImage="RetainShape" hAlign="Center">
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="159" height="76" uuid="5033480f-8a9b-400a-8c95-8bbb79101452"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{logo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

Am using jasper plugin in netbeans and i have a problem when displaying an image.I get the following errors :

```
Error filling print... Unknown image source class [B 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unknown image source class [B      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:559)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:472)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
```

Comment: Sub report doesn't have an image. In fact the sub report is running when i add   default expression. The problem comes in when run the main report that has the image field the image is saved in postgresql database as bytea

Comment: Fwiw the next JasperReports version will allow directly using byte arrays (which is what you seem to get for the byea column) as image expression.  See https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/commit/88d77c8591eedf0a70e82008d2345b312d91c762